# Does Sanatana Dharma Endorse Animal Sacrifice?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, rig-veda, animals, yajna, sacrifice

I've heard in Vedic ***yajna***, the ***sacrifice*** of animals was a must. Nevertheless, Vedic texts are riddled with ***contradictions***. I've also heard of SrimadBhagavad Gita and Puranas which endorse animal sacrifice before goddesses ***Kali*** and ***Durga***. I'm curious to know the Right stance of the Vedic Sanatana dharma as well as SrimadBhagavad Gita and Puranas on animal sacrifice.